# Find largest sum of 3 numbers which is also divisable by 3

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, numbers

How to find largest sum of 3 numbers which is also divisable by 3?
Examples:
Input: [1, 15, 4, 7, 2]
Output: [15, 7, 2] (In that order)

Input: [1, 2, 4, 7]
Output: [1, 4, 7] (In that order)

I came up only with this:

```
function largestSum(arr) {
    let max = -1;
    let nums;

    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        for (let j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++)
            for (let k = j + 1; k < arr.length; k++)
                if ((arr[i] + arr[j] + arr[k]) % 3 === 0 && arr[i] + arr[j] + arr[k] > max)
                    nums = [arr[i], arr[j], arr[k]], max = arr[i] + arr[j] + arr[k];

    return nums;
}
```

But, isn't it better option here (with better efficiency)?

Comment: Maybe you can improve that time by sorting the array first, but i think your code is quite good already.

Comment: One minor tweak might be to change the order of the conditions in the if-statement so that the > max is checked first to avoid doing the more-expensive modulus unless you actually need to. (Would probably need massive arrays for that difference to even be measurable, I suspect).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved in linear time and constant space using modular arithmetic, no need to sort the input or enumerate its combinations.

```
Save:
  the largest three elements congruent to 0 mod 3
  the largest three elements congruent to 1 mod 3
  the largest three elements congruent to 2 mod 3

Choose the largest of:
  1. the sum of the largest three elements congruent to 0 mod 3
  2. the sum of the largest three elements congruent to 1 mod 3
  3. the sum of the largest three elements congruent to 2 mod 3
  4. the sum of the largest element congruent to 0 mod 3
                and the largest element congruent to 1 mod 3
                and the largest element congruent to 2 mod 3
```

Comment: As I fell asleep last night I wondered about a solution like this but you've done it. This is great.

Answer (score 0):

If you sort the numbers first in descending order, then find the first solution which is divisible by three, this will be the largest value.

At it's worst, it's worse than your solution as it does everything yours does as well as sorting BUT at it's best it could be one sort and one test.

It's using the greedy algorithm.

Comment: Yes, but then output of second example will be [7, 4, 1] and not [1, 4, 7] am I right?

Comment: Yes but you could also record the position of the numbers and then sort on this (you're only sorting three numbers) at the end.

Comment: Edit: wait, but how do you record position of the numbers in original array when on the beginning you don't know what 3 numbers will be in output?
 You have to record all numbers on the beggining am I right?

Comment: You would have to copy all the numbers into an array of pairs recording number & position first. This would be O(n). The quick sort would be O(nlogn). Then the greedy algorithm is (at worst O(n^3) and at best O(n).

Comment: Mine is O(n) at worst :)

Answer (score 0):

can't believe there is a way to do it without trying all the combinations of the array [what you've already done]

Answer (score 0):

Another simple solution with a simple combination algorithm and check for the wanted parameters.

```js
function getCombinations(array) {
    function add(a, b) { return a + b; }

    function fork(i, t) {
        var sum = t.reduce(add, 0);
        if (i === array.length) {                
            if (t.length === 3 && sum % 3 === 0 && sum > result.reduce(add, 0)) {
                result = t;
            }
            return;
        }
        fork(i + 1, t.concat([array[i]]));
        fork(i + 1, t);
    }

    var result = [];
    fork(0, []);
    return result;
}

console.log(getCombinations([1, 15, 4, 7, 2]));
console.log(getCombinations([1, 2, 4, 7]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This still checks all possible solutions, despite it being recursive so is of the same Order as the original post.